From databricks I need to consume messages from my even hub using managed Identity
For databricks managed Identity I have assigned Azure Eventhub sender as well as Receiver Roles.
When I try to consume from eventhub using SASL Plain text its failing due to
java.lang.RuntimeException: non-nullable field authBytes was serialized as null
Not sure how to approach this, If anyone came across this issue can you please let me know
getting java.lang.RuntimeException: non-nullable field authBytes was serialized as null

Provide the code you are trying to consume from eventhub using SASL plain text.

@JayashankarGS My Kafka Parameters are as below
"kafka.bootstrap.servers": "shravan.servicebus.windows.net",
"kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
"kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
"kafka.request.timeout.ms": "60000",  # Increase timeout to 60 seconds
"kafka.group.id": "$Default",  # Consumer group ID
"subscribe": "test",
kafka_options[] = f"org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='$connection_string' password='f"Endpoint=sb://shravan.servicebus.windows.net/;EntityPath={eventhub_name};Authentication=ManagedIdentity"
';"

When using a connection string, it must contain an Endpoint, EntityPath (the Event Hub name), SharedAccessKeyName, and SharedAccessKey. Refer to this. So, you cannot use a managed identity in the connection string.
However, you can authenticate using a service principal. For that, you need to create a callback class which retrieves the token and uses it to read Event Hub data. According to this, you can create a callback class and read data.
Alternatively, follow Stream processing with Apache Kafka and Databricks | Databricks on AWS for using the built-in class in Databricks.
To authenticate using managed identity credentials, you need to create a callback class similar to the one mentioned in the above document, which returns a token using ManagedIdentity credentials.
